# Center of a mass for linear $f$ over $E$ with $(x,y,z)\in E \iff (x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta,x\sin \theta+y\cos\theta,z)\in E$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, physics

Let $E\subset \Bbb{R}^3$ be a measurable set (i.e. $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}1_{E}$ exists) and let $v(E)\ne 0$. Let $f$ be a linear function $f:\Bbb{R}^3\to \Bbb{R}$, and let $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ be the center of mass of $f$,which in the question is also presented, as a remainder, as $f(x_0,y_0,z_0)={1\over v(E)}\int_{E}f$. Show that if there is $\theta\in (0,2\pi)$ such that $(x,y,z)\in E \iff (x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta,x\sin \theta+y\cos\theta,z)\in E$, then $x_0=y_0=0$.

I posted a similar question a few days ago, but here I am pretty confused. I really can't seem to understand how the ranges of $x$ and $y$ look in the integral itself. I also don't really see how it matters that these are trigonometric figure and how I can use it(no change of variables seems useful or relevant here.).

Is there any way to determine the bounds for $x$ and $y$ in the integral, say, $\int\int\int_{E}f(x,y,z)xdxdydz$?

Comment: That vector corresponds to a rotation about the z axis of the original one.

Comment: That's quite a progress for me, thank you!

Comment: The rotation is a path of something? 
Does it means something particular that the rotation is applies by a funtion of $\theta$? I can't arrive at a pattern.

Comment: Okay the determinant is $1$ (of the rotation,) 
It used to mean something to me but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: $\vec{r'} = R_z (\theta) \vec{r}$, with the matrix defined as here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix in the section "in three dimensions".

Comment: The determinant is one, so $dx dy dz = dx' dy' dz'$, in other words, rotating an object doesn't change its volume

Comment: Physically, the implication seems to be: If you can rotate the system around the $z$-axis in such a way that the mass distribution doesn't change, then the center of mass is on the $z$-axis.

Comment: So I basically need to use a change of variables?

Comment: I simply look at the center of mass over $A(E)(=E)$, The volume remains the same and I arrive at $x_0={1\over V(E)}\int\int\int_{E)}x f(x,y,z)dxdydz=x_0={1\over V(E)}\int\int\int_{A(E))}(x\cos\theta-y\sin \theta) f(x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta,x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta,z)dxdydz$.Am I correct?